# How to Redirect to a POST url and pass data in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, payfort

I'm trying to integrate payfort payment gateway using the redirection method. it requires redirecting to a POST url and submitting some data. the data contains confidential values like access code and merchant code, so i don't want to expose them in HTML.

Is it possible to redirect to a POST URL from a django view and submit the data?
or should I use ajax to perform the signature calculations and submit the form using jquery. I'm kind of lost. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can invoke post request from django view using `urllib` (built-in) https://instructobit.com/tutorial/110/Python-3-urllib:-making-requests-with-GET-or-POST-parameters or `requests` module https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Comment: does this open the URL in the browser? because, card details and other info has to be entered on the redirected page. the post URL needs to be opened on the browser by passing the parameters and their values

Comment: No. In that case, what you need is to use is django `redirect` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: @YohanesGultom Does it support POST requests

Comment: @ArunLaxman What do you mean *"redirect to a POST URL"*? There is no such thing as a "POST URL". There's just a URL. And then you can make GET or POST or some other type of request to that URL.

Comment: @xyres what I mean is that the Payfort URL only supports POST requests. so I need to submit some form data to that URL. and that URL needs to be open in the browser so that user can enter the remaining details like card number and cvv etc.

Comment: @xyres Thanks for the effort man. but I guess I have no choice since Client has already setup the payfort account. I guess I'll have to stick with Jquery and take things from there.

Comment: @ArunLaxman did you got any solution for this